# How do I balance these numbers in a rock-paper-scissors attack system?

Tags: mathematics, probability

I have three arrays of numbers. If you take a random one from x, it will 'win' more times than a random number from z, which will win more times than a number from y, which will win more times than a number from x.

However, the distribution is not equal.

y beats x 51% of the time, being beaten by x 46% of the time

x beats z 46% of the time, being beaten 42% of the time

z beats y 52% of the time, being beaten 46% of the time

How can I change these to make them approximately equal, winning more than 50% of the time?

Each array must have every number from 0 to 21, add up to the same amount (currently 735) and be of equal length. The closer the probabilities are the better, the higher the better, with as few numbers as possible.

x = [21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,11,10,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,8,7,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,5,4,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,1,0]

y = [21,20,19,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,17,16,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

z = [21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,1,0]

Comment: Those numbers don't add up to 100%. What happens in the remaining matches?

Comment: @Phillipp The two numbers are the same.

Comment: @Philipp the missing % are the draws due to even-matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look into the concepts behind [non-transitive dice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nontransitive_dice).

Briefly, it's a set of dice such that:

```
P(A beats B) > 50%
P(B beats C) > 50%
P(C beats A) > 50%
etc...
```

As an example, consider these 3 dice:

```
A = { 2, 2, 4, 4, 9, 9 }
B = { 1, 1, 6, 6, 8, 8 }
C = { 3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7 }
```

Then:

```
5/9 = P(A beats B) = P(B beats C) = P(C beats A)
```

Not all non-transitive dice have equal probabilities like this example set does.

Answer (score 4):

What matters is not the total of all the numbers but the ratio of how many numbers in one set win/lose against ALL the numbers in the other set.

To understand this you need to simplify your set to an extreme example:

`A=[96, 1, 1, 1, 1]` vs `B=[22, 21, 20, 19, 18]`

**Both sets add to a total of 100.**

However it's easy to see how in A vs B, **A will win only 1 time out of 5**.

To balance you need to **compare each number on each set to each number in the other set and count the wins vs losses** and adjust to insure an equal number of win/lose.

For example:

`A=[96, 100, 20, 1, 1]` vs `B=[22, 21, 20, 19, 18]`

A has a total of 218, B has a total of 100, however they will have an equal number of wins when randomly matched.

Table of where A wins with the new set:

```
A B:22, 21, 20, 19, 18
96   W   W   W   W   W
100  W   W   W   W   W
20   L   L   E   W   W
1    L   L   L   L   L
1    L   L   L   L   L

W=Win, E=Even, L=Lose

Wins: 12
Lose: 12
Even: 1
```